# Unresolved reference @HiltAndroidApp or any other Hilt annotation in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-studio-4.0, dagger-hilt

I have done everything properly but still, I can't use Hilt in my project.

**build.gradle(:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"


    buildFeatures{
        viewBinding = true
        dataBinding = true
    }



    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.emptysheet.pdfreader_autoscroll"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.7"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

// To inline the bytecode built with JVM target 1.8 into
// bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.6. (e.g. navArgs)


    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.2.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation project(path: ':android-pdf-viewer')

    //firebase for crashlytics
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:17.4.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.0.1'
    // for ads
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.1.0'
    // multidex
    //room
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-ktx:2.2.5'
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.5"

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.7"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.0"
    //debug database
    debugImplementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.6'
    implementation 'de.psdev.licensesdialog:licensesdialog:2.1.0'
    //support for APK less than 21
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    // in app billing
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing-ktx:3.0.0'
    // Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.28-alpha"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28-alpha"

}
```

**build.gradle(Project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.1.1'
        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.28-alpha'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

When I am using `@HiltAndroidApp` or any other Hilt annotation. It says Unresolved reference. Create annotation. I have tried re-installing Hilt but it's still not working.

I am also using **Android Studio 4.0**

Comment: Try `File` -> `Invalidate Caches / Restart ...` (and click `Invalidate and Restart`).

Comment: Also did you add `import dagger.hilt.android.HiltAndroidApp` in your `Application` class?

Comment: Thank you so much.. Invalidate Caches / Restart worked...If you write it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the usual:

`File` -> `Invalidate Caches / Restart ...` (and click `Invalidate and Restart`)

Answer (score 1):

1. From the toolbar, press 'Sync Project with Gradle Files'.
2. Invalidate Caches / Restart